# »Keine« or »nicht«

Tags: english-to-german

> Ich habe keine Möbel.
>   Ich habe nicht viele Möbel.

Both of these sentences are supposed to be correct, but why?
What is the difference between *keine* and *nicht viele*?

Comment: They don’t even mean the same thing.

Comment: I would be curious about your mother tongue. Because in none of the languages I know, "no[ne]" and "not many" mean the same thing. If that is the case in your mother tongue, I would find that really fascinating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sentences are different:

"Keine Möbel" would be "**no** furniture".
"Nicht viele Möbel" would be "**not a lot** of furniture".

Don't forget the Umlauts öäü, and don't forget to write nouns with a capital letter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Nicht viele Möbel"?

Comment: @infinitezero of course :)